How do I get data from a js function?
In my Flutter application, there is a call to the js function "get User Push()" at the click of a button. The result is written in INFO:CONSOLE. Please tell me how I can get this data for recording for future use?
onPressed: () async {
        //controller.runJavaScript('getRole()');
        //String? s = stdin.readLineSync();
        //Future  regionName  = controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult('getUserPush()');
        Future  userId  = controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult('getUserPush()');
        userId.then((data) {
          String hZonesInt = data.toString();
          print(hZonesInt);
        },
            onError: (e) {
              print(e);
            });
        },

Information displayed in the console:
I/chromium(14500): [INFO:CONSOLE(1300)] "37", source: ************* (1300)

I tried to decrypt the returning value from the function itself, but I always got null. I also tried to read directly from the console, but I also got null.

You can create a variable (let's call it "foo") before invoking that onPress function.
Then whenever you get result from the runJavaScriptReturningResult, assign (in .then() block) the result to the variable you create beforehand so later on you can just call that foo variable to read its value.
late final foo;
onPressed: () async {
  try {
    Future userId  = await controller.runJavaScriptReturningResult('getUserPush()');
    foo = data;
  }
  catch (error) {
  //handle any error or just print it out
  }
}

Hope this helps you a bit.

Your answer really helped a little, thank you very much. But in foo, null is written, not the information displayed in the console. Can you please tell me what this might be related to?

hi @FandomReveller, have you heard of StatefulWidget (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)? It can help you store your data from response your get from server and use the data inside that widget. Or try some state management packages (https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) such as Get package (https://pub.dev/packages/get).
My pseudo code above is just giving you an idea of how to assign data you get to a variable so you can read it later.
It will be great if you post your complete code so I can understand your problem better.
